# OpenCL - communication between workgroups

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

Can i make a work group communicate with another workgroup without using  global-memory? If yes, how?

Using local memory is at least 10 times faster and using registers are even 50 times faster than global memory. But I guess these memories do not reach outside of workgroup.

Thanks

Comment: You could post the code, and we can discuss the implementation metodology to improve the design, because I anticipate that that situation could be avoided.

Comment: Code is a simple all-pairs-Nbody code that needs N*N memory operations while gpu can easily do 50-60 register operations at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't communicate work-groups, each work-group is an isolated computing part that runs in parallel to all others.

The only method to communicate workgroups is by spliting the kernel in two kernels, and saving the output of kernel 1 in global memory. After that, using it as input to kernel 2 to continue the processing.